# PHP Performance Load Comparing Two DateTime Objects

Tags: php, performance, datetime, comparison

I have an availability class which does many checks to see if a date is available, but one of these checks is to see whether the bookable product is within the booking window (i.e. in the future enough to meet the user criteria for same day bookings). The code is below -

```
private function set_within_booking_window(){
    $timezone = get_option('timezone_string');
    $starttime = cb_get_product_starttime($this->product_id, $this->date);
    $this->starttime = $starttime;
    //get booking window
    $window = new DateTime();
    $window->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $buffer = get_option("cb_same_day_buffer");
    $window->add(new DateInterval("PT".$buffer."H"));
    $this->window = $window;
    if($starttime < $window){
      $this->within_booking_window = false;
    } else {
      $this->within_booking_window = true;
    }
  }
```

Upon performance study, this entire operation is well-built and speedy EXCEPT the DateTime Comparison of if($starttime < $window) which basically KILLS the performance of this entire availability class. A pageload is less than 1 sec with that expression commented out and more than 26 seconds with it left in.

Everything I've read in the PHP documentation suggests that this is the best way to compare the two dateimes - but this just cannot be right...

Any feedback on performance when comparing two PHP DateTime Objects?

Comment: How are you profiling and are you running opcache? What does cb_get_product_starttime return?  Have you tried the [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method?

Comment: I am developing locally MAMP with PHP 7.1.22. Profiling with Chrome Developer tools performance. I spent a few hours reworking my class to optimize the cb_get_product_starttime because I assumed that was my performance drain, but in fact after fully optimizing this call I realized that it is from the datetime comparison. I have tried using the DateTime::getTimestamp() and then compare with no improvement. I have not tried DateTime::diff

Comment: Trying datetime::diff made no improvement.

Comment: 26 seconds is an eternity.  Have you instrumented this to log actual execution time in the complete absence of xdebug and with your IDE process actually dead (eg as close to production-like running conditions ) ? You could be actually measuring some side effect of the development harness.